# Debian package `vlc-data` causes `error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)`

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, vlc

I am running Debian 9.1. There is a package that isn't upgrading correctly on my system: `vlc-data` version 2.2.7-1~deb8u1. This is apparently required by `libvlccore8`. This may well be a continuation of an issue I opened months ago in my question, [Why does this apt-get remove have such deep consequences?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371825/why-does-this-apt-get-remove-have-such-deep-consequences). But this issue cropped up after having resolved the one from that question.

Unfortunately there is a big nexus of dependencies here which means I must get this package working. Can someone help? After updating the package lists (`sudo apt-get update`) I did the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libvlccore8 : Depends: vlc-data (= 2.2.7-1~deb8u1) but 2.2.6-1~deb9u1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Upon following the recommendation to perform `apt --fix-broken install`, I am met with the following:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  vlc-data
The following packages will be upgraded:
  vlc-data
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,906 kB of archives.
After this operation, 37.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 324197 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../vlc-data_2.2.7-1~deb8u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking vlc-data (2.2.7-1~deb8u1) over (2.2.6-1~deb9u1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/vlc-data_2.2.7-1~deb8u1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo', which is also in package vlc-l10n 2.2.6-1~deb9u1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/vlc-data_2.2.7-1~deb8u1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is the output of /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.8.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20170506-14:10]/ jessie main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.8.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20170506-14:10]/ jessie main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian jessie stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian jessie stable
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jessie contrib
# deb-src http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jessie contrib
```

### Update:

After performing `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/vlc-data_2.2.7-1~deb8u1_all.deb` (as per a comment) I tried to update and upgrade, resulting in the following output:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Hmm, seems like the AutoRemover destroyed something which really
shouldn't happen. Please file a bug report against apt.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavcodec-dev : Depends: libavcodec56 (<= 6:11.11-99) but it is not going to be installed or
                           libavcodec-extra-56 (<= 6:11.11-99) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libavcodec56 (>= 6:11.11-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed or
                           libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11.11-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libavresample-dev (= 6:11.11-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
 libavformat-dev : Depends: libavformat56 (= 6:11.11-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
 libavutil-dev : Depends: libavutil54 (= 6:11.11-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
 libfreerdp-plugins-standard : Depends: libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not going to be installed or
                                        libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11.9) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libavutil54 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (>= 0.10.22) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.24) but it is not going to be installed
 libquicktime2 : Depends: libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not going to be installed or
                          libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11.8) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libschroedinger-1.0-0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libswscale3 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not going to be installed
 libswscale-dev : Depends: libswscale3 (= 6:11.11-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
 python-samba : Depends: python-ntdb but it is not going to be installed
 samba-libs : Depends: libntdb1 (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
 winbind : Depends: samba (= 2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Internal Error, AutoRemover broke stuff
```

### Update

Removing all my sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and running `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/vlc-data_2.2.7-1~deb8u1_all.deb` seems to have resolved my issue. Thanks @GAD3R

Comment: `apt-get update`

Comment: @IporSircer I did that before the `apt-get dist-upgrade`. I will update this to say so.

Comment: The current version of vlc-data is 2.2.7-1~deb9u1 in debian stable.

Comment: @IporSircer Thanks. I thought that I took care of stuff trying to go into unstable territory a couple of months back, so I'm not sure what's causing this one.

Comment: @GAD3R Added. For what it's worth, see this post of mine a couple of months back: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371825/why-does-this-apt-get-remove-have-such-deep-consequences

Comment: In your preferences set the stable `Pin-Priority: 1001` remove the  `vlc*` package ,  upgrade your system then reinstall `vlc`

Comment: @GAD3R I've added the pin, though note that in the post I mentioned, I had deleted all pins as per the answer, so the pin you mentioned is the only existing pin now. Furthermore, `sudo apt-get remove vlc*` fails due to globbing on quite a few packages that I do not have installed--including, as it turns out, vlc itself. So I'm unable even to do the first step you asked.

Comment: `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite  /var/cache/apt/archives/vlc-data_2.2.7-1~deb8u1_all.deb` then update and upgrade your package to see if there are an error.

Comment: Thanks for your help @GAD3R. There was an error after `dist-upgrade`; please see my update above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69256/discussion-between-gad3r-and-brandon-arnold).

Comment: ^ A question I opened months ago, this could well be the same issue and a continuation of it.